# jquery mouseenter and mouseleve is not working on newly injected dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have the following code. It works fine but when i add new elements into the dom it does't show or hide it.

```
jQuery("div.cat-icon").on({
       mouseenter: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.catselect').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.catselect').hide();
    }
});
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically added elements require delegated event handlers :

```
jQuery(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.catselect').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.catselect').hide();
    }
}, "div.cat-icon");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event delegation for dynamically added elements, for which the syntax is

```
jQuery(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.catselect').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.catselect').hide();
    }
}, "div.cat-icon");
```

In event delegation model, you need to bind the handler to an already existing element and then pass the target element selector as the second argument to `on`